# Could not open input file: /Users/me/composer.phar - After running source ~/.bash_profile.save

Tags: php, command-line, laravel-4, composer-php

this is giving me a headache. Simply trying to install laravel 4.

So, installed composer fine and it runs correctly. The issue is that when i tryed to install laravel i was recieving this error:

```
- laravel/framework v4.2.9 requires php >=5.4.0 -> no matching package found.
```

So, I checked the PHP version that terminal was using and using:

```
which php
```

gave me the usr/local/bin location and then php -v showed that was 5.3 php.

So, following some instructions I edited the .bash_profile.save so that the path was now:

```
alias composer='php ~/composer.phar'
export PATH=/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.5.14/bin:$PATH
^R
```

I then ran:

```
source ~/.bash_profile.save
```

And then again which php.

This showed the correct path BUT... when trying to use composer i recieved this error:

Could not open input file: /Users/me/composer.phar

So now im stuck. Is it because of the alias composer line? Where should that now be pointed?

Thanks, just want to get on with laravel... :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to have composer in that directory below

`mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer`

And not in your user account's root

Answer (score 1):

Just get this `composer.phar` in the composer web site and put it in the same place where you have `composer.json`; this is all you need.

https://getcomposer.org/download/1.2.0/composer.phar